# Problem when bootstrapping Juju with MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, mongodb

I'm a newcomer of ubuntu cloud.

Recently, I'm trying to install maas and juju on my servers.

Installation of maas is all right,but not juju.

When I ran

```
juju bootstrap -e maas
```

,after waiting for a while, I got the error below

```
WARNING juju.replicaset replicaset.go:98 Initiate: fetching replication status failed: cannot get replica set status: can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

I really have no idea about what cause this error(seems like juju-mogodb cause this problem, but I'm not sure)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks very similar to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1412621

The work for this problem is still going on.  Please add yourself to the bug by clicking on "Does this bug affect you?" link. The comments might offer some insight on the problem.  Some comments even offer workarounds.